# Prototype to jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, prototypejs

Currently in using Prototype on my site.

I was wondering if there is an alternative jQuery function, to this Prototype function:

```
new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater('content', '/shouts/update.js', { method: 'get', frequency: 3});
```

thx,

Oded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    $("content").load("/shouts/update.js", function(data) {
        // Handle data manually. God knows what your update.js file is doing
    }));
}, 3000);
```

Relies on [`$.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load) and [`window.setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval)

Comment: it's weird because the setInterval function works for "alert("test")", but it doesnt work for $.load

Comment: @Oded Harth are you pointing at the right URL? Is the content selector a sizzle selector? Is the URL your loading a HTML file? It seems like your url is JS file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the same Prototype library function ported to JQuery:

[JQuery PeriodicalUpdater](https://github.com/RobertFischer/JQuery-PeriodicalUpdater/)